# GROUP_CONCAT value not recognized in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have written a stored procedure.   Both shipmentnumbers and cartonid should return comma separated values. shipmentnumbers are coming properly i.e comma seperated values but cartonid  always returns only one value even if there are multiple rows. How do i solve this problem.

```
 DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_deleteOrderData`(orderid BIGINT(11))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE shipmentnumbers VARCHAR(1000);
        DECLARE cartonid VARCHAR(1000);

        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a_shipmentid) FROM t_shipment WHERE a_orderid = orderid INTO shipmentnumbers;

        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a_cartonid) FROM t_carton WHERE a_shipmentid IN (shipmentnumbers) INTO cartonid;

    SELECT shipmentnumbers;
    /*SELECT  cartonid;  */
    END$$

    DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not give the following a try, using an inner join to match up all combinations

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_deleteOrderData`(orderid BIGINT(11))
BEGIN
    DECLARE shipmentnumbers VARCHAR(1000);
    DECLARE cartonid VARCHAR(1000);

    SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(a_shipmentid),
        GROUP_CONCAT(a_cartonid)
    INTO
        shipmentnumbers,
        cartonid
    FROM t_shipment ts
    LEFT JOIN t_carton tc
    ON tc.a_shipmentid = ts.a_shipmentid

    WHERE ts.a_orderid = orderid;

    SELECT 
        shipmentnumbers,
        cartonid;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

If you are trying to delete from those tables though you can probably do so more effectively with some joins i.e.

```
DELETE ts,tc
FROM t_shipment ts
LEFT JOIN t_carton tc
ON tc.a_shipmentid = ts.a_shipmentid
WHERE ts.a_orderid = orderid;
```